# TTPhotoViewController data reload

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ttphotoviewcontroller

has anyone figured out how to reload data in TTPhotoViewController?

I have done several attempts but never worked out a suitable solution.

Your help is much appreciated.

Vlad

Answer (score 1):

TTPhotoViewController ultimately derives from TTModelViewController so you should be able to call the `reload` method. From TTModelViewController.h:

```
/**
 * Reloads data from the model.
 */
- (void)reload;

/**
 * Reloads data from the model if it has become out of date.
 */
- (void)reloadIfNeeded;

/**
 * Refreshes the model state and loads new data if necessary.
 */
- (void)refresh;
```